# Logic implementation for conversion of decimal to hexadecimal and vice versa

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have two radio button Decimal and hexadecimal and a textbox when i switch between two radio button the input in textbox should convert from decimal to hexadecimal and vice versa and decimal is in format of octets like 111,255,111.111,225.255.111.255

I need logic to convert decimal to hexa and vice versa like for example if decimal is 111.111.111 it should convert hexadecimal to 6F6F6F(excluding periods) when convert hexadecimal to decimal it will display

111.111.111(including periods) in UI

Some examples

```
111.111.111(DECIMAL) - 6F6F6F(HEXADECIMAL)
125.255.123(DECIMAL) - 7DFF7B(HEXADECIMAL)
7D(HEXADECIMAL) - 125(DECIMAL)
FF(HEXADECIMAL) - 255(HEXADECIMAL)
```

NEED HELP IN LOGIC IMPLEMENTATION

Comment: This is an interesting conversion but to me there is a glaring problem. If your hex number isn't the full 6 digits in length it could mean there are multiple interpretations for example: AB3A could mean 10.179.10 or it could mean 171.3.10 or even 10.11.58, I'm not sure how you wish to solve this. You could have a system where the binary is like A-B3-A signifying which characters are assigned to which number or alternatively you could make sure the hex number is always formatted to have 6 digits like 0AB30A or something. If you let me know how you would wish to solve this I can write an answer.

Comment: Like sir it is just for conversion decimal in address form to hexadecimal just for UI purpose like decimal I have 111.111.111 it will convert to 6F6F6F I mean it will check number between decimals point and convert to hexadecimal excluding periods there

Comment: Like hexadecimal will be 00-FF RANGE ONLY

Comment: Ok, I'm going to finish it alongside the other things I'm working on. Will be ready soon.

Answer (score 0):

I have made the solution as you have requested from the comments.

### Converting an "octet" to a hex string

This method takes an input of integers smaller than 256 separated by periods such as "111.111.111" and will return a hex string such as "6f6f6f"

```
public static string ConvertToHex(string Octets) 
{
    // Extract each part of the octet into individual number strings
    string[] numberStrings = Octets.Split('.');

    // Convert those strings to integers
    int[] numberList = Array.ConvertAll(numberStrings, s => int.Parse(s));

    // Create a string to store the final output in
    string HexString = string.Empty;

    // Loop through all the numbers in the int list
    foreach (int number in numberList)
    {
        // Convert the integer to a hex string and pad left with 0
        // This will ensure the hex number is always two digits long
        string HexSection = Convert.ToString(number, 16).PadLeft(2, '0');

        HexString += HexSection;
    }

    return HexString;                    
}
```

### Converting a hex string into an "octet"

This method takes a hex string as input with each hex value taking up two digits and representing a base 10 value smaller than 256 such as "6f6f6f" and will output an octet string which consists of numbers smaller than 256 separated by periods such as "111.111.111"

```
public static string ConvertToOctet(string Hex) 
{
    // Determine the length of the Hex string
    int Length = Hex.Length;

    // List to store all the hex we have converted to ints
    List<int> NumberList = new List<int>();

    // Calculate the length divided by two so the loop can iterate over each hex number which is two digits long
    int Iterations = Length / 2;

    // Loop through all the sections in the hex string
    for (int i = 0; i < Iterations; i++) 
    {
        // Extract the hex number which we know is two digits long
        string HexSegment = Hex.Substring(i * 2, 2);

        // Convert it to its integer value
        int Value = Convert.ToInt32(HexSegment, 16);

        // Add the int to the list of ints
        NumberList.Add(Value);
    }
    // Create a final list of octets split with a period
    string OctetString = string.Join(".", NumberList);

    return OctetString;
}
```

You can test the methods with the following code:

```
// Should output "6f6f6f"
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToHex("111.111.111"));

// Should output "c0a817fe78c86428"
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToHex("192.168.23.254.120.200.100.40"));


// Should output "111.111.111"
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToOctet("6f6f6f"));


// Should output "192.168.23.254.120.200.100.40"
Console.WriteLine(ConvertToOctet("c0a817fe78c86428"));
```

Thanks, please mark my answer as the accepted and upvote if this helps